# Apache mod_rewrite from a folder to a different domain doesn't work with trailing slash

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to rewrite URLs from `old.domain.tld/project` to `domain.tld/subfolder/project` using `.htaccess` in the `project` directory on the old server. I think I need to check for the host name so the rule only applies to the old server, even if the .htaccess file is also put on the new server.

I've tried the following `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^old\.domain\.tld$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://domain.tld/subfolder/project/$1 [R=301,L]
```

This works fine for URLs like `https://old.domain.tld/project/index.php?p=q` (redirects to `https://domain.tld/subfolder/project/index.php?p=q`) but not for the URL without the trailing slash—`https://old.domain.tld/project` ends up being redirected to `https://domain.tld`. Very odd! How do I make this work for both types of URL?

I tried a rather different method to make this a generic redirect, that could be included even if the folder name wasn't `project`, but this has the same problem:

```
 RewriteEngine On
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^old\.domain\.tld$ [NC]
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.*)$
 RewriteRule . https://domain.tld/subfolder/%1 [R=301,L]
```

In a server-wide configuration, a slash is appended to all requests for index files, e.g. `old.domain.tld/project` is redirected to `old.domain.tld/project/`. Could this be causing a problem?

Comment: Do you have any other rules  in htaccess?

Comment: Not in this .htaccess. But the top-level .htaccess does. The first rule there, however, is `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]`
`RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d`
`RewriteRule . - [L]` ... most everthing should hit that, yes?

Comment: Try adding `DirectorySlash On` in top level .htaccess assuming `project` is a real directory.